# SQLPlus Line size

Tags: oracle, bash, shell, line, sqlplus

I am writing shell sripts and i need to connect db via sqlplus. when i execute that code

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(sqlplus -s username/password@DB  << EOF
set linesize 32000;
set trimspool on;
SELECT * FROM number.IMEI_BLACK WHERE IMEI_14 = '22222224444444' and rownum < 10;
/
exit;
EOF)
echo $result
```

the result is this, lines are not proper and cannot be read like this. I set linesize 32000 and trimspool on, but didn't work. What other edit or configuration should i make ?

I`D IMEI_14 IMEI_15 REASO TIME_ADDE TIME_TO_B NOTIFIED_TO_NETWORK C_FIRST_DETERMINATION_GROUP ---------- -------------- --------------- ----- --------- --------- ------------------- ------------------------------------ 123456789 222222224444444 2222222244444444 9999 09-DEC-13 14-DEC-13 0 ID IMEI_14 IMEI_15 REASO TIME_ADDE TIME_TO_B NOTIFIED_TO_NETWORK C_FIRST_DETERMINATION_GROUP ---------- -------------- --------------- ----- --------- --------- ------------------- ------------------------------------ 1234567829 2222223344444444 22222233444444442 9999 09-DEC-13 14-DEC-13 0`

Comment: Did you try saying `echo "$result"` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `echo "$result"` that ought to do the trick.